# Test the existence of a page/article by its URL, taking in consideration the URL rewriting by filters

Tags: php, permalinks, filters, url-rewriting, slug

I have this line in `functions.php`:

```
add_filter('post_link', function($link, $post) { return str_replace('foo-', 'foo/', $link); }, 10, 2);
```

and now Wordpress successfully sees `example.com/foo/bar` as *the permalink* of the article of slug `foo-bar` (let's say this article exists).

(I also added a rewrite rule to redirect `/foo/*` to `foo-*`).

Strangely

```
echo get_page_by_path('/foo/bar', OBJECT, 'post') ? 1 : 0;
```

still returns `0`, whereas `echo get_page_by_path('/foo-bar', OBJECT, 'post') ? 1 : 0;` returns `1`.

This means that `get_page_by_path` does not take in consideration the permalink rewritten by `post_link` filter. Why?

Question: I need to be able to **test the existence** of a page/article for a given URL (taking in consideration the URL rewritten by the `post_link` filter!). Since `get_page_by_path` doesn't do that, is there another option?

Example: I need `get_page_by_path('/foo/bar', OBJECT, 'post')` to be `true` because an article of slug `foo-bar` exists + the `post_link` filter transforms it (successfully for other things except this question) into `foo/bar`.

Comment: The answer to your "why?" is that the `post_link` filter is only applied when using the function `get_permalink`. Outside of that context, your `/foo/bar` path doesn't exist.

Comment: @vancoder Is there a way to apply the `post_link` filter to a wider context than just `get_permalink`? How would it be possible to test the existence of a page/article by a given URL, based on *modified*  URLs (modified by `post_link` filter)?